# Javascript Regular Expression: Only matching the last pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

**Context:** I have some dynamically generated HTML which can have embedded javascript function calls inside. I'm trying to extract the function calls with a regular expression.

**Sample HTML string:**

```
 <dynamic html>

   <script language="javascript">
       funcA();
   </script>

 <a little more dynamic html>

   <script language="javascript">
       funcB();
   </script>
```

My goal is to extract the text "funcA();" and "funcB();" from the above snippet (either as a single string or an array with two elements would be fine). The regular expression I have so far is:
`var regexp = /[\s\S]*<script .*>([\s\S]*)<\/script>[\s\S]*/gm;`

Using `html_str.replace(regexp, "$1")` only returns "funcB();".

Now, this regexp works just fine when there is only ONE set of `<script>` tags in the HTML, but when there are multiple it only returns the LAST one when using the replace() method. Even removing the '/g' modifier matches only the last function call. I'm still a novice to regular expressions so I know I'm missing something fundamental here... Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I've done a bit of research already but still haven't been able to get this issue resolved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea, but this can work if you never have any `<script>` or `</script>` in strings within your JS code...

Answer (score 5):

Your wildcard matches are all greedy. This means they will not only match what you expect, but as much as there possibly is in your code.

Make them all non-greedy (`.*?`) and it should work.